# Set a variable in a controller, make some operation and return a new value cakePHP 3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am using cakePHP 3 and I am trying to set a variable in a controller, use that variable in a function and then pass the new value depends on the `queryString` the function received.

All this is through ajax's calls.

This is the code and the function I wrote in the controller:

```
public $taskEditor;

public function checkState(){
    if($this->request->query('isFirstTime')){
        $value = $this->taskEditor = false;
    }else{
        $value = !$this->taskEditor;
    }
    die(json_encode($value));
}
```

This and others intent Did not work. The variable `$taskEditor` must store a boolean value. I also try setting a global variable and the set the value in the function `beforeRender(Event event)`, but Did not work. 
The response is always false and/or cake don't recognize the `$taskEditor` variable.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you access `checkState()` the controller is initialized, so `$taskEditor` is reseted.

You could write this value on session:

```
public function checkState(){
    $session = $this->request->session();
    if ( $this->request->query('isFirstTime') == 'true' ) {
        $taskEditor = false;
        $session->write('taskEditor', $taskEditor);
    } else {
        $taskEditor = $session->read('taskEditor');
        if ( is_null($taskEditor) ) {
            $taskEditor = true;
        }
        $session->write('taskEditor', !$taskEditor);
    }
    die(json_encode($taskEditor));
}
```

See [Reading & Writing Session Data](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/sessions.html#reading-writing-session-data).

Comment: So, you are passing $this->request->query('isFirstTime') always true.

Comment: @Rayann, pretty sure you meant to reference the session object there, not Configure.

Comment: @GregSchmidt sure, thank you, I made a quick updated.

Comment: @RayannNayran i pass the fist time true, and the next time always false. And always return false the method, even with the new modification you did.

Comment: Ok @MaggieFortelli I updated the answer, please, check again.

Comment: YES! @RayannNayran now is working! So everytime I want to do similar operation need to store the value in session, right?

Comment: Right, because the Class's variables are reseted each time the Class is initialized.